# Why must a subclass' using statements be duplicated?

Tags: c++, using, subclassing

Relatively new to cpp. When you subclass a baseclass, the #include cascade to the subclass, why don't the class-wide usings in the cpp file also cover the scope of the subclass? Is this a historical or pragmatic reason? Err.. What is the reason?

```
//available to subclass
#include <cinder/app/appBasic.h>

// have to duplicate in subclass
using namespace ci;
using namespace ci::app;
using namespace std;
```

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly you're wondering about? Where's the class and subclass here? Also, includes and namespaces are completely orthogonal concepts. Are you wondering about: `class A { using namespace ci; ...}`, `class B : public A {...}` and why you have to `using namespace` again in `B`?

Comment: You shouldn't be `abusing namespace std` anyway.

Comment: Basically, I've got a base class with usings and also have to repeat the usings in the subclass. I guess it's kind of a silly question now, as with c# or java you'd still import the dependencies in a derived class regardless of the base inclusions, unless the base class also sub-classed all the dependencies, which is not likely.

Comment: on using std... I'm not writing a 10-year epic project or API. This is a little app, the ends, not the means. It will likely never get used as a component. =)

Answer (score 1):

`using directive` and `using declaration` are only valid for the current translation unit. you can put these in the header file which is not a good practice.

Answer (score 1):

The main reason is that the compiler only looks at one `.cpp` file plus whatever it `#includes`. It has no idea what `using` statements there might be in the `.cpp` file for your base class. For that matter, it has no idea whether you've even written the `.cpp` file for the base class yet when you compile the `.cpp` file for the derived class. And it's not going to go rooting around the filesystem to find out, unlike for example `javac`.

Furthermore, I guess you're writing one `.cpp` file per class, and giving the file a name that has something to do with the class name. But C++ doesn't require that. You can have more than one class in a file, or for that matter you could split a class across multiple files if you want to.

So, you know that this `.cpp` file is *the* file for your derived class, and that the other `.cpp` file is *the* file for the base class, and therefore you think it might be convenient if some stuff from the other `.cpp` file was lifted into this `.cpp` file. But the compiler knows no such thing. It wouldn't make sense to the C++ compiler to talk about what's in *the* file for the base class.

Finally, a reason that is principled rather than pragmatic: just because it is convenient for the implementer of the base class to bring the names from certain namespaces into global scope doesn't mean the same will be true of the implementer of the derived class. The derived class might not use `ci::app` at all, let alone use it so much that the person writing the derived class is sick of typing it. So even if C++ *could* require the compiler to fetch those `using` statements (which, given the compilation model, it can't), I'm pretty sure the language's designers wouldn't want it to.

> the `#include` cascade to the subclass

No they don't. Any `#include` in the `base.h` will be included into `derived.cpp` if (for example) `derived.cpp` includes `derived.h` which includes `base.h`. But any includes in `base.cpp` have no effect on `derived.cpp`.

This is all assuming that you follow the usual naming convention. There's nothing other than convention to stop you including a `.cpp` file from `derived.cpp`, in which case (1) any includes or `using` statements would apply in `derived.cpp`, but unfortunately (2) you'll probably break your build system, because most likely you won't be able to link `base.o` and `derived.o` together any more on account of them containing duplicate definitions for code entities subject to the One Defintion Rule. That is, functions.